# Windows Phone - Set dark theme for application

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, themes

Is it possible to set the whole theme of an application to the dark one from the phone settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a theme as default for your application.use JeffWillCox's [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager)
Hopes this helped you.

Comment: Thank you
I think there is no better way than this!

Answer (score 0):

You can colour your application as you wish (if branding demands) - it is recommended to use the system styles and themes though.